# Is it possible to change the datatype of a column in a view?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, view, sqldatatypes

Usually I run a script like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLE]
ALTER COLUMN [Column] NVARCHAR(40);
```

The result is that the field in the table gets converted to nvarchar. But what is the syntax for doing the same thing for a view? Or is that even possible?

Comment: You can't dictate the data type for the output column of a view. The best you can do is as @buckley suggested - use CAST or CONVERT to force an explicit data type inline in the view definition.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Sure

```
CREATE VIEW AView
AS
SELECT CAST(title AS char(50))
FROM titles
```

So check out CAST and also CONVERT on the msdn pages for full info

Answer (score 3):

If you have updated the type in the table and the view still reflects the old type, simply running an alter view without changing anything will update the type

Comment: Thank you for contributing, but I don't think this answer adds anything new or useful to the discussion.

Comment: I respectfully disagree, why not let the original asker decide

Comment: I know this was a while ago, but this was the first SO post that came up and this answer answered my question. I think it's related enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yes..You can try Convert function to do this.

```
Convert (Desired datatype,column name)
```

eg.`Convert(varchar(50),dbo.User_master.User_email)`
where User_email has previous type as nvarchar(MAX).

If you want to convert nvarchar data to datetime then additional parameter is needed to Convert function like

```
CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)
```

eg.  `Convert(Datetime,dbo.User_master.User_DOB,103)`

more info at [SQL Server CONVERT() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)