# View Column as Boolean

Tags: mysql, view

I'm trying to create a view with a column type as boolean or tinyint(1), but I'm not sure how to customize the datatype. Previously this question was answered by saying, use cast() or convert(). I can't do that here as mysql doesn't allow boolean as an output type.

I've also tried using

```
if(`mytable`.`mycolumn`=1,TRUE,FALSE) AS myAlias
```

Unfortunately myAlias in the view is created as a bigint(20)

Here's the similar question I was talking about where casting was suggested. My reputation isn't high enough for me to post a comment there, so I decided to make a separate question. 
[Is it possible to change the datatype of a column in a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711473/is-it-possible-to-change-the-datatype-of-a-column-in-a-view)

Thanks

Comment: When I try this, `desc viewname;` says the type is `int(1)`.

Comment: You can also use `select mytable.mycolumn = 1 as myAlias`