# Saving an SQL column conversion through entire query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-view

**Situation**

I am trying to construct a query, using a column name: TxnDate (TransactionDate) which is of type `INT`. Typical dates look something like this:`YYYYMMDD`, so `20180209` or `20171025` as examples. I am unablt to change this fact, otherwise many things will break. It is stuck in this stupid format, unfortunately.

However, it is only useful to me as the data type `DATE`, so I must first convert it in a roundabout way: `CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(char(8), TransactionDate))`

And to further complicate things, some of the dates are null, negative, or zero, for various reasons. So in order to get it in a usable form, I need to check to make sure that it can be converted:

`CASE WHEN ISDATE(TxnDate)=1 
      THEN CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(CHAR(8),TxnDate))
 END`

The records with bad date data are of no use to me.

The problem is that I need do check and then convert this in many different places in the `WHERE` statement. This has ballooned my query to slightly ridiculous proportions. I would appreciate some wisdom on a cleaner and more succinct manner of proceeding.

**What I have Considered**

I am reluctant to add things to the schema, but will do so if it is the better option:

1) Creating a view, which casts for me, and which I can query from, in place of the table, as demonstrated here: [Is it possible to change the datatype of a column in a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711473/is-it-possible-to-change-the-datatype-of-a-column-in-a-view) I am not partial to this, as there may be problems when attempting to cast, which invalidates the whole purpose.

2) Creating a user defined function which just runs the `CASE` expression when called.

3) I have tried many different variations of aliases for variables, and using the `AS` expression in many different ways to try and define it in one place only, but to no avail. It might be possible, but I have not been able to find it by either my own efforts or by internet search.

Again, I would appreciate any wisdom on this matter, I am  new to SQL, so if there is an obvious solution, or a duplicated question, please point it out. Further, if you feel something is wrong about this question, I would prefer if you were to tell me what was incorrect, before down-voting so I get a chance to improve and learn.

Thank you

Comment: Changing the schema would be better IMHO. If you know C#, then you could write a function that would do this check and conversion for you. It would be easier to write then writing in T-SQL and that function would be part of your database (look at SQL server CLR support).

Comment: Yes, change the schema. Keeping data in the wrong data type is just asking for complications and problems. newer versions of SQL have TRY_CAST function you can use to test if the data can be converted to something else, but that is NOT the way to go. It is just a lot of work, indexing will not work, you will have to implement the same workaround everywhere. It is just lose lose

Comment: store dates as dates is going to be your best option here

Comment: I hear what you guys are saying, but I don't have an option when changing the datatype.  There is a LOT of legacy code which relies on it being an int, which is certainly going to break if I change it. I know, whoever did it that way was a buffoon, and I am cursing them every five minutes at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You could use the query given at the end of this test. I had to generate the dummy data matching your specifications to perform the test, but all you need is the SQL at the end that produces the date column (Transaction_Date) you need.

```
create table #test1 (
    TxnDt int
)
go

insert #test1 values(20180328)  -- March 28, 2018
insert #test1 values(20170220)  -- Feb 20, 2017
insert #test1 values(20161201)  -- Dec 1, 2016
insert #test1 values(2016)      -- bad data 
insert #test1 values(1)         -- data
go 

select distinct * from #test1
go 

TxnDt
1
2016
20161201
20170220
20180328
```

-- Assuming the correct data will alays be in the form yyyymmdd, you can run the following SQL to convert it to a date type

```
select *
from 
(
    select distinct TxnDt 
        , case when len(cast(TxnDt as char(8))) = 8 
            then convert(date,substring(cast(TxnDt as char(8)),5,2) + '/' + substring(cast(TxnDt as char(8)),7,2) + '/' + substring(cast(TxnDt as char(8)),1,4))    
        end as Transaction_Date
    --  , case when len(substring(cast(TxnDt as char(8)),5,2) + '/' + substring(cast(TxnDt as char(8)),7,2) + '/' + substring(cast(TxnDt as char(8)),1,4)) = 10 then TxnDt end
    --  , convert(date,substring(cast(TxnDt as char(8)),5,2) + '/' + substring(cast(TxnDt as char(8)),7,2) + '/' + substring(cast(TxnDt as char(8)),1,4))   TransDate
--into #test2
    from #test1
) main
where main.Transaction_Date is not null
go

TxnDt   Transaction_Date
20161201    2016-12-01
20170220    2017-02-20
20180328    2018-03-28
```

Comment: select *
from 
(
 select distinct TxnDt 
  , case when len(cast(TxnDt as char(8))) = 8 
   then convert(date,substring(cast(TxnDt as char(8)),5,2) + '/' + substring(cast(TxnDt as char(8)),7,2) + '/' + substring(cast(TxnDt as char(8)),1,4)) 
  end as Transaction_Date
 from #test1
) main
where main.Transaction_Date is not null
go

Comment: Date math Transaction_Date, to substantiate our solution:              
select main.TxnDt 
 , main.Transaction_Date
 , dateadd(mm,2,main.Transaction_Date) AS DateMathPerformed
from 
(
 select distinct TxnDt 
  , case when len(cast(TxnDt as char(8))) = 8 
   then convert(date,substring(cast(TxnDt as char(8)),5,2) + '/' + substring(cast(TxnDt as char(8)),7,2) + '/' + substring(cast(TxnDt as char(8)),1,4)) 
  end as Transaction_Date
 from #test1
) main
where main.Transaction_Date is not null
go
TxnDt Transaction_Date DateMathPerformed
20161201 2016-12-01 2017-02-01
: