# Is it possible to change the structure of a column in a view from varchar to date

Tags: mysql

I currently have a column ('kWhdate') in a view ('appdatatest') that takes a timestamp column and converts it to a date.

```
 date_format(`t`.`value_timestamp`,'%d/%m/%y%y') AS `kWhDate`
```

The above is part of the Create View query. It is currently stored as VARCHAR(10). I would like to convert it to a Date. I have tried the following:

```
 ALTER VIEW appdatatest MODIFY appdatatest.kWhDate datetime
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE(appdatatest.kWhDate, Date) FROM appdatatest
```

I have looked at this question [Is it possible to change the datatype of a column in a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711473/is-it-possible-to-change-the-datatype-of-a-column-in-a-view) but it gives an answer for SQL Server not MYSQL

If possible I could convert in the original CREATE VIEW query

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `timestamp` to a `date` with `date()`.

```
SELECT date(kwhdate) kwhdate
       FROM appdatatest;
```

Comment: Thanks @sticky bit, but I’m trying to change the structure from varchar to date in a view. The reason is I need to pull the data through as date as I can’t change it in Power BI